# How do I subset these zero values out?

Tags: r

I am new to R, I get some vectors such like `vec <- c(1,5,0,6,9,10,20,0,6)` and I want to apply a `log()` function to them but 
don't want the value `-Inf` remaining in the result. How can I avoid this by subset the value "0" in the
orginal vectors?

Comment: The "do it before" and "do it after" answers provided both will do the job for values exactly  equal to zero.  If you suspect your data has some tiny values (e.g. 1E-30), you'll need to decide whether you desire to have these values removed or not.  If you do, use the same method as in the answers but use `lvec<-lvec[lvec> -1e20]` (arbitrary choice of huge neg. logarithm) or `log(v[v> 1e-30])`

Answer (score 4):

In this instance it may be easier to remove them *after* applying `log()` using the `is.finite()` function:

```
> vec <- c(1,5,0,6,9,10,20,0,6)
> lvec <- log(vec)
> is.finite(lvec)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
> lvec[is.finite(lvec)]
[1] 0.000000 1.609438 1.791759 2.197225 2.302585 2.995732
[7] 1.791759
```

Note there is the opposite function `is.infinite()` to identify the `Inf` and `-Inf`

```
> is.infinite(lvec)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

To do what you want you can always identify which are equal (not equal) to zero and remove (select) those elements, as in

```
> log(vec[vec != 0]) # select *not* zero elements
[1] 0.000000 1.609438 1.791759 2.197225 2.302585 2.995732
[7] 1.791759
> log(vec[!vec == 0]) # don't select the zero elements
[1] 0.000000 1.609438 1.791759 2.197225 2.302585 2.995732
[7] 1.791759
```

Answer (score 2):

```
v <- c( 1,5,0,6,9,10,20,0,6)

log(v[v!=0])  # log to all values but 0's
log(v[v>=1])  # log of all non-negative and non-zeroes values log(v[!v<=0])
log(pmax(v, 1)) # all 0's are set to be 1, then applying log
```